# Dynamic paths return 404 in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

So i created a directory in `routes/` named `blog` and inside `blog` i have 2 files one named `[blog].svelte` and `+page.svelte`. I have watched multiple videos and have read quite a lot of articles and they all say and demonstrate that it should work as expected:

`GET /blog -> blog.svelte`

`GET /blog/hello -> [blog].svelte`

But instead when i try to `GET /blog/hello -> 404` It returns a 404 error.
Could someone explain why this does not work or if it has been changed?
Edit: fixed look in answers...

Answer (score 0):

This may have worked in older versions of SvelteKit, new versions require a folder and `+page.svelte` per route, [see the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing).

So you need:

```
blog/+page.svelte
blog/[blog]/+page.svelte
```